# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[libraryWebProject.Major]' to type 'libraryWebProject.Major'

Tags: linq, casting

I have this code in the code behind file

```
LibraryArticlesEntities la = new LibraryArticlesEntities();
int id = 17;
if (Request.QueryString["TitleID"] != null)
{ 
        id = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["TitleID"]);
}
var gettitle = la.Titles.Where(t => t.ID == id).Select(t => t.Title1);
header.InnerHtml += gettitle;
var sub = la.Titles.Where(t => t.ID == id).Select(t => t.Majors);
        foreach (Major major in sub) // the error is here
        {
            subject.InnerHtml += major.MajorName + "&nbsp;";
        }
```

Here I'm using a LINQ query to fetch a list of majors but I get this error when I try to iterate over it and display their names:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[libraryWebProject.Major]' to type 'libraryWebProject.Major'.

The relationship between Title and Major is many to many and I have an association table linking Title ID and Major ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var sub = la.Titles.Where(t => t.ID == id).Select(t => t.Majors);
```

and the fact that "The relationship between Title and Major is many to many" 
implies that the result of the `Select` is a collection of collections, so your loop will have to be:

```
foreach (var listOfMajors in sub)
{
    foreach (var major in listOfMajors)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

*Old answer replaced after it was revealed that the question didn't actually include the code that was in error.*

Comment: It works now. Thanks. But I don't understand I select only a single title and then select the majors associated with it. how can it be a collection of collections?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to make `sub` a `List<Major>` by adding `.ToList();` at the end of your select.

```
var sub = la.Titles.Where(t => t.ID > 0)
                   .SelectMany(a => a.Majors.Select(b=>b)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `ToList()` and use `var` in `foreach`:

```
var sub = la.Titles.Where(t => t.ID == id)
                   .Include(t => t.Majors)
                   .Select(t => t.Majors).ToList();//use tolist() here
        foreach (var major in sub) // and add var here please
        {
            subject.InnerHtml += major.MajorName + "&nbsp;";
        }
```

Comment: @twobits did you change 'Major' and 'var'

Comment: when I add var it loses the definition for MajorName inside the loop

Comment: @twobits are you sure? you can't lose it i used many time like this

Comment: Yes. I can't access MajorName if I add it

Comment: My last suggestion add include maybe majors getting nulls i hope this help have good day @twobits